# Установить время в константу | C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Как записать время. Без даты! в константу. Просто интересует переменная которая хранит 11:30 независимо от даты. 
Пытался делать вот так но это туповато

```
11 <= System.DateTime.Now.Hour ?? 30 <= System.DateTime.Now.Minutes
```

Так же пытался вот так

```
startTime = new DateTime(2015, 7, 20, 11, 30, 00);
        string startTimeString = startTime.ToLongTimeString();
        startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTimeString);
```

Все равно на выходе получаю в переменной startTime время и дату, хотя метод `ToLongTimeString()` ее вырезает норм но хранит в стринге.
Уверен есть нормальный способ определить переменную. Буду признателен за помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) ==> `Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понял, что вы имеете ввиду под "11:30 независимо от даты". Возможно, вам подойдет TimeSpan, который представляет интервал времени:

```
public static readonly TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(11, 30, 0);
static void Main()
{
    //остальной код
}
```

Ваш перевод даты в строку и назад можно упростить:

```
var startTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 11, 30, 1);
```